How to Handle Single Observations in Mixed-Effects Modeling with Debiased Lasso of Unbalanced Data?
I have a dataset of samples collected from hundreds of people with different clinical conditions. The dataset is very unbalanced. For example, the number of samples varies between subjects. About 20% of the whole dataset consists of a single sample. 5% consists of 2 samples and the rest consists of 3 to 15 samples. There are also microbiome data corresponding to these samples.
I am interested in investigating the mediating effect of the microbiome.
Since the microbiome data is high-dimensional, I want to use the lasso regularization technique to deal with multicollinearity. I plan to use debiased lasso to eliminate bias in lasso estimates. I also have multiple observations from individuals, so I will use mixed effects modeling taking individuals's ID as random effect.
My question is: Since I will use the results of the model in mediation analysis, how should I handle single observations from individuals in such a way that they continue to contribute to the overall model?

Welcome to Cross Validated, Seda :)
If I understand correctly, your data is unbalanced and consists of samples from subjects where 20% of the data are for subjects with only one sample, and you are concerned about these particular samples. The good news is that mixed effects models are very good at dealing with unbalanced data, even when there are a lot of singleton clusters, so unless I am missing something, you don't need to do anything specific to handle these singletons. You might find it useful to check my answer here:
Minimum sample size per cluster in a random effect model
This establishes that the minimum sample size is 1 ! Having said that, and as also mentioned in the linked answer above, there can be computational problems when the proportion of singletons is very high but in my experience 20% is not high. That doesn't rule out that you won't get computational problems, but a priori it shouldn't. Obviously you should specify your model appropriately (eg, do not fit random slopes since that really doesn't make a lot of sense for a group with only 1 observation).
The other issue you raise is to do with using LASSO. I have not used it, but there is a fairly new package in R - glmmLasso, which will hopefully do what you need.  Again, this isn't something I have done, but I have heard of people using "normal" LASSO (ie, not part of a mixed model package) to determine variable selection of fixed effects, and then use those fixed effects in a mixed model. So that's something else you might want to explore
I hope this helps !

+1. Singleton clusters, while uninformative when it comes to intra-subject dependence, they still carry information for their variance at time $t$. Ultimately that is what we mostly care when using LASSO anyway, so we are fine.
